# Is it possible to by pass auto run restrictions on windows 7?

Tags: windows, exploit

I'm trying to create a startup on a windows 7 for the machine and current user (its a workstation meaning all user data is saved on a server).

What i mean whit a startup is to have a program run at login producing the same result as to put a registrar value in bout:

```
HKEY_USERS\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Or adding a link/file in the following folders:

```
%allusersprofile%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
%profilepath%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

What I want to achieve is a proof of concept. I want to create a "virus" that when run, it creates a startup for the local machine and user when run. so i want to be able to create startups both for the current user and machine to make this work. Hopefully the user startup will get stored in its personal preferences that is stored on the account server making that user a distributer of the startup "virus". So all user that gets infected will spreed it and all clients that get it will also spread it.

**I can't:**

- Use the registry
- use elevated privileges

**I can:**

- Write to C:/
- Run .exe
- Run the activity monitor

I know this isn't a lot to go on. So just ask and i will check if the feature is available.

### Edit

I basically rewrote the whole question to make it more understandable.

Comment: @WZeberaFFS - I'm lost.  What do you mean by "autorun"?  For some people, "autorun" refers to something that automatically executes when a particular removable media is inserted.  For others, it's something that runs at OS boot.  For still others, it's something that runs at user login.

Comment: @Iszi I'm sorry, I wan the run at login feature. Like the registry keys `HKEY_USERS\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Comment: @WZebraFFS - Any particular preference as to which of those you want to emulate?  The former is user-specific, while the latter applies to all users.

Comment: @Iszi I want them both. So that when a user log into a infected computer the virus will spread the user personal setting that then gets saved on the server. And when that infected user logs into another computer it will to get infected.

Comment: @WZeberaFFS - Without knowing certain variables in the environment, I don't think there's a way to do this reliably.  With certain kinds of roaming profiles though, this may be possible:  Copy virus to "%profilepath%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" for per-user, multi-system infection.  Single-system, multi-user infection may be more difficult since the equivalent action would be copying to the same sub-folder under "%allusersprofile%", which requires elevated privileges.

Comment: @Iszi, that sounds like the correct answer, if that's what the OP is looking for. @WZeberaFFS, if it is, please edit the question accordingly to clarify.

Comment: @AviD @Iszi Thank you for the suggestion. And i will update the question to clarify. I have to stop posting questions when its past 2am...

Comment: By "can't use elevated privileges" I presume this also precludes any privilege escalation exploits?

Comment: @Iszi I have not tried any actually i have never used one before. But i will have a look on privilege escalation exploits. BTW did the edit improve the question?

Comment: @WZeberaFFS - The question does look a good deal better.  Still, I doubt the level of infection you're looking to achieve will be possible without some form of privilege escalation.  You may want to specify in the question whether or not you want to include such exploits in the solution.  Also, I believe most OS-level privilege escalation vulnerabilities tend to be relatively short-lived, with a regular patching schedule in effect.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why did you add "write to the registry"? It should be trivial for a program to write to their own registry hive.